# How to speed up the process of new dag showing up to web GUI in Apache Airflow?

Tags: airflow

I added a new DAG in my `~/airflow/dags` and it takes a long time for the new DAG to appear in the UI in the following steps:

- First the dag name appears and I get the the warning that DAG is only available locally.
- Then the pause button appears after about 1-2 minutes

I am guessing that airflow has some sort of interval to check for new dags and inserts them into the db. My question is that is it possible to speed up the process of thw new DAG showing up to the back end database? May be doing this like:

- Reducing the search interval
- Having a scripts to run manually and check the dagbag for possible new dags and inserts to database.

Comment: What is value is `dag_dir_list_interval` set to in your airflow configuration?

Comment: @OluwafemiSule The default value is 300

Comment: @motam79 Did you ever find a reason for this or a solution to speed up the update to UI?